# How to set containerId when I call Highsoft().Highcharts

Tags: model-view-controller, highcharts

I'am trying to use Highchart in my MVC project.
I set containerId name for placing chart on the page, using next code:

```
@model MyProjectModel
@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts;
...
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Machines.Count; i++)
{
<div id="@Model.Machines[i].containerName"></div>
    @(Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(
new Highcharts ({...}, Model.Machines[i]);
}
```

and Chart don't place in div
but then I set containerId next way

```
...
new Highcharts({...}, "container");
...
```

It's ok.

How I can set containerId in code?
Thank's for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm wrong, but why the div id is set as `id="@Model.Machines[i].containerName"` and then you are passing just `Model.Machines[i]` to Highcharts constructor? Try to provide the containerName:

```
@model MyProjectModel
@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts;
...
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Machines.Count; i++)
{
<div id="@Model.Machines[i].containerName"></div>
    @(Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(
new Highcharts ({...}, Model.Machines[i].containerName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That's exactly what I've tried to do, but it didn't work. At last after many various attempts I found this parameter would work correctly & accept container's name on condition that this name doesn't contain the dash symbol (beside meeting requirements to the ID-naming). I.e. if I attribute to the container the name "xxx-name-yyy", it wouldn't work. <b>Naming it as "xxxnameyyy" allows to solve the problem, everything goes</b>